# 3rd party User Auth with Electron

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, electron

I've been looking for resources on how to implement user auth in an Electron App.

I'd like to utilize third party services like Github to allow users to login and signup. With a "regular" Node.js application, I would likely utilize something like passport.js or similar to implement this.

My confusion arises because Electron apps are client side, so having things like your client secret keys in client side code seems wrong. So what is the process of implementing 3rd party user auth in Electron apps?

Comment: As of now, you will have to have your client secret keys on the client side and yes it is indeed wrong, but that's the way it seems to be at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

Think of electron app as a standard browser page.
Then you will have standard oauth2 flow.

First of all you need middleware server where you will store clientId and clientSecret for third party services.

You need to create something like session between electron app and middleware server (below I will show example).

Below I will show example process to authorize github.

You need use https.

Lets assume that your middleware server is available on example.com. Your need minimum two endpoints :

1. GET: https://example.com/initAuth/
2. GET: https://example.com/oauth/token

Github client_id and client_secret are stored only in this server.

Your electron app send GET request to `https://example.com/initAuth/`.
And your server should generate two uuid's. Which should be stored as pair (for example in redis). One uuid is for `state` parameter in authorization github link and second one as simple session/token to identify your electron app.
Your server should build url to github access [github access](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#1-redirect-users-to-request-github-access) :

`GET https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize`

where

1. `redirect_uri` will be your second endpoint - https://example.com/oauth/token
2. `state` will be your first uuid
3. other parameters as usual.

Now you return from this endpoint to electron session/token uuid and built url.

Your electron show link with target="_blank" - it should be opened in separe tab/window. Electron should remember session/token uuid.

When user click link he will get into oauth process where he accept your app. And then he will be redirected to your middleware server second endpoint (https://example.com/oauth/token)

Your server will get in this endpoint `code` and `state`. YOur server should check if it has registered electron app with this `state`. And if it exist then server need exchange `code` and `client_secret` for `access_token` (I will not explain it - this is standard oauth flow).
Now store it in temporary storage (redis) access_token and both uuid's.
And as response render html view with script which will close this tab or just normal html view with some message.

Your electron app need to know if middleware server has access_token.

1. Electron can polling time to time middleware server by sending to third endpoint session/token uuid. And if there is access_token server will return it.
2. You can use websockets
3. Your main window can check if second "oauth" window is closed and then send request to middleware server for access_token.

Or alternativly you can store access_token in your middleware server and your electron wont send requests to github but only to your server and your server will send requests to github and responses return to electron.

Comment: Very clear answer. But one thing I don't understand: once a user has granted access to GitHub via your middleware server, isn't the middleware server now open to attacks? E.g. if that same user navigates to a malicious website that makes JavaScript calls to your middleware server, can't it obtain a GitHub token and have access to the user's account? I think CORS won't even help here because the middleware server has to allow wildcard origins in order to let electron apps call it.

Comment: thanks. Please check last paragraph. It shows safer method. First of all, there is no way to get github access token from middleware. Middleware doesn't have method which will return it. Middleware makes requests to github based on received requests from electron. In the worst scenario malicious code could cheat middleware to do some defined action. But it should not happen because middleware will do only actions if electron send with requests session uuid.

Comment: But how does the middleware know that it is the electron app that's initializing a session rather than some other malicious app? I must be missing something.

Comment: you never can trust your frontend app (in this case electron). You never can be sure that right now call is from your app. If different app does everything correctly then it should get same correct result. But this result should affect only one user who used it. No one else. If somebody use hacked version of your app then in worst case he will suffer. You need to provide trusted source of your app (google, mac windows legal stores for example). If customer is using correct/legal version of your app and he does authentication then his credentials should be safe not vulnerable on attacks.

Comment: if you have more custom case maybe you should describe it in more details and maybe we will figure something out

Comment: This method is insecure. You should never embed your secret in a client application.

Comment: Not sure if this comment is to my answer. Where did you read in my answer that secret is or should be stored in a client application? Second paragraph "First of all you need middleware server where you will store clientId and clientSecret for third party services." and from the middle of my response "Github client_id and client_secret are stored only in this server.". If you need some more explanation please ask and I will help, or if you think that some point is confusing please highlight it.